# One class representing multiple structs (with different members) safely

Tags: c++

I receive input data which contains different message types. For each message I extract the relevant details to a general `ReturnObject` struct:

```
void processMessage(const std::byte& bytes, ReturnObject& obj)
{
    switch(msgType)
    {
        // Extract message type 1 fields
        // Extract message type 2 fields
        // etc
    }
}
```

Lets say message 1 has these fields:

```
int a;
int b;
char c;
string d;
```

Message 2 has some overlap:

```
int a;
string d;
double e;
float f;
```

(There are about 20 different messages in total)

At the moment `ReturnObject` contains the superset of the fields:

```
struct ReturnObject
{
    int a;
    int b;
    char c;
    string d;
    double e;
    float f;
};
```

I'd like `ReturnObject` to be type-safe and represent one message at a time. When it represents message 1, only `a`, `b`, `c` and `d` are accessible. One instance will only represent one message type at a time.

What is the best way to achieve this in C++20?

Comment: Sounds like you may want a [union](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/union).

Comment: @JesperJuhl I was thinking about union but then i wasn't sure if std::optional would be a choice?

Comment: Another case for `std::variant`..

Comment: @KamilCuk sorry, I meant variant, not optional!

Comment: `std::variant<obj1, ob2, ..., objn>` would be my starting point.

Comment: you can also change each optional field to `std::optional`, depends on real fields and their overlap between variant, this may be a good way.

Comment: and if applicable, I'd recommend always resolve types as early as possible, like `ProcessMessage<MessageType>(bytes)` (of course only if the type is useful information)

Comment: @appleapple I think I know what you mean, although I don't think it would be within processMessage as at that point I don't know the message type (yet). It's effectively known in the first line (I omitted for brevity)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would consider polymorphism. This looks like a factory pattern. Your `processMessage` could just return a pointer to an appropriate object. No need to control access as the irrelevant members simply are not present.